# ValueError: Shapes (?,) and (?, 1) are incompatible

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning

I am attempting to use some of the `tf.metrics` functions on my `eval` data for a binary classification problem. I have been using `tf.metrics.accuracy()` with no errors, but when I use `tf.metrics.mean_per_class_accuracy()` I get the following:

> ValueError: Shapes (?,) and (?, 1) are incompatible.

I have seen some related posts but they are quite old and seem to have been fixed by updating tensorflow to a (now out of date) version. I am running tensorflow 1.5.0.

```
eval_metric_ops = {
  "accuracy": tf.metrics.accuracy(
      labels=labels, predictions=predictions["classes"], name="accuracy"),
  "per_class_accuracy": tf.metrics.mean_per_class_accuracy(
      labels=labels, predictions=predictions["classes"], num_classes=2, name="per_class_accuracy")
  }
```

Anyone know what might be happening? Thanks in advance!

Comment: From the documentation: `ValueError: If predictions and labels have mismatched shapes, or if weights is not None and its shape doesn't match predictions, or if either metrics_collections or updates_collections are not a list or tuple.` Have you already checked this? Also, for further help the rest of your code could help.

Comment: If the tensors you are comparing are really of shapes (?,) and (?, 1) then you will have to reshape either of them, because the first one is a 1-dimensional tensor and the second one a 2-dimensional one, hence these are indeed incompatible